# alternating find replace words python

Tags: python, function, dictionary, replace, find

Here is the code I have so far

```
replace_listA = {'Bear': [Black, Woods], 'Duck': [Bird, Feathers]}
replace_listB = {'Bear': [Grizzly, Woods], 'Duck': [Quack, Feathers]}
replace_listC = {'Bear': [Grizzly, Black], 'Duck': [Quack, Bird]}

with open("main.txt") as main:
    words = main.read().split()
replaced = []
for y in words:
    replacement = replace_listA.get(y, y)
    replaced.append(replacement)
text = ' '.join(replaced)
print (text)
new_main = open("main.txt", 'w')
new_main.write(text)
new_main.close()
```

Two things I need to get working is that for each time the word Bear or Duck appears I would like the code to use the first value and then remove it from the list. so taking replace_listA as an example the first instance of the word Bear is replaced with the word "Black" and the second instance is replaced with the word "Woods".

That is the first thing,

The second thing is to then rotate between the 3 replace lists when both values have been used for either Bear of Duck and a new value is needed, (Both values have been used for "Bear" and the word Bear has come up again)

So a list of words

```
Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck Bear Bear Bear Bear Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck Bear Bear Bear
```

would become

```
Bird Black Woods Feathers Quack Grizzly Woods Grizzly Black Quack Black Woods Bird Feathers
```

because each list would in turn replace

```
replace_listA
Duck Bear  Bear  Duck 
Bird Black Woods Feathers

replace_listB
Duck  Bear    Bear
Quack Grizzly Woods

replace_listC
Bear    Bear  Duck
Grizzly Black Quack

replace_listA
Bear  Bear  Duck Duck
Black Woods Bird Feathers
```

Comment: Would you cycle the list on the basis of all replacements being consumed for both keys or  cycle the dictionaries independently for each key.  If they cycle independently then there is no benefit in having 3 separate dictionaries and you could/should merge the replacement dictionaries for each key before starting the process. `{'Bear':['Black','Woods','Grizzly','Woods','Grizzly','Black'] ...`

Comment: "Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck Bear Bear Bear Bear Duck" becomes "Bird Black Woods Feathers Quack Grizzly Woods Grizzly Black Quack", and as the OP explained it, you change from listA to listB to listB when `either Duck or Bear needs a new value`. So they don't cycle independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a list of dictionaries, this list will be the successive replacements you'll do, you can cycle through this list:

```
words_input = "Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck Bear Bear Bear Bear Duck Bear Bear Duck Duck"

replacements = [{'Bear': ["Black", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Bird", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Woods"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Feathers"]},
                {'Bear': ["Grizzly", "Black"], 'Duck': ["Quack", "Bird"]}]

output = []
index_replace = 0
count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
for word in words_input.split():
    if count_replace[word] == len(replacements[index_replace][word]):
        # We need to cycle through the replacements
        index_replace = (index_replace + 1) % len(replacements)
        count_replace = {key: 0 for key in replacements[0].keys()}
    idx_word = count_replace[word]
    output.append(replacements[index_replace][word][idx_word])
    count_replace[word] += 1

output_words = ' '.join(output)
print(output_words)
# Bird Black Woods Feathers Quack Grizzly Woods Grizzly Black Quack Black Woods Bird Feathers
```

(Beware, your example seems not totally accurate, since the last "Bear Bear Bear" are not translated in your original post)

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for, thank you. Do you know how to insert the word "CHANGE" into the output for each time the dictionary changes.

Comment: When you are in the `if count_replace[word] == len(replacements[index_replace][word]):`, this means that there is a "dictionary change", there you can output "change" inside `output`

Comment: output.append("CHANGE") thanks

Comment: What if the main text file also contained other words, any woy to ignore them in them so they are not effected by the over all code, thanks.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry but StackOverflow is not a help desk. If you have a specific question about programming you can post a new question, but if you're searching for help in your coding, maybe other platforms could be more adapted.

Comment: cool, thanks anyway